# add autoplay to basic jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery

Im making a basic jQuery slider for class. and would like to have it autoplay playing the next slide after 5 seconds but haven't used the timer before it isn't doing what I thought it should do. It waits for the proper interval and then keeps triggering the callback function.

```
//basic slider on click
$('.slider>ul>li').click(function()
{
    $('.slider>ul>li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
    right=$(this).index()*745;
    $(this).parent('ul').parent('.slider').children('div').children('ul').animate({'right': right}, 1000, 'easeOutBack');
})

//attempt to use timer plugin to auto play
$('.slider>ul>li').timer(
{
        delay: 1000,
        callback: function()
        {alert($('.slider>ul>li.current').index())
            if($('.slider>ul>li.current').index()!=3)
            {
                $('.slider>ul>li.current').next('li').click();
            }else//oddly this doesn't trigger at all
            {
                $('.slider>ul').first().click();
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: What number does your alert show?

Comment: http://ocd.classelliott.com/# is the hideous website I'm implementing on for class.

Comment: What about an alert w/in your `else` block that you said isn't triggering?  I'm wondering if you need to do `$('.slider>ul>li').first().click();` there so it's actually finding the first `LI` and not just the first `UL`.

Comment: it goes back to the first one now but stops. and it still is triggering all of them without a pause in between.

Comment: What does the timer plugin do? Can you post a link to its download page?

Comment: http://code.cyntaxtech.com/plugins/jquery-timer
but i do not have to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var i = $('.slider>ul>li.current').index();
  var next = (i < 3 ? i+1 : 0);
  var items = $('.slider>ul>li');
  $(items[next]).click();
}, 5000);
```

EDIT:
changed setTimeout to setInterval and bumped time to 5sec;  this should now loop.